# Is there a way to update api key value using sdk?

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

I need to update the api key value using my lambda function.

I looked through [API Gateway SDK Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/APIGateway.html) and I thought updateApiKey was the best option, but when I send the request, I get an error as return:

```
BadRequestException: Invalid patch path  'value' specified for op 'replace'. Must be one of: [/description, /enabled, /name, /customerId]
    at Object.extractError (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:51:27)
    at Request.extractError (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/rest_json.js:55:8)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
```

Basically, it is saying that I can't update "value", so I couldn't do what I need

For now, my code is that:

```
let sendPromise = null;
let params = {
    "apiKey": "xxxxxxxxx",
    patchOperations: [
        {
            op: "replace",
            path: "value",
            value: "teste123"
        }
    ]
};

sendPromise = new AWS.APIGateway().updateApiKey( params ).promise();

try {
    const data = await sendPromise;
    return criarResposta( 200, `{
        "message": "OK"
    }` );
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err, err.stack);
    return criarResposta( 500, err.stack );
}
```

Is there any other function to update the api key value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no other function to update the api key value. I think this is by design.
I do not know this for sure but there is *evidence* that AWS designed the apikey resource's value attribute immutable:

- The AWS REST api for ApiGateway is the service's endpoint which supports the largest subset of operations available. The attributes which support modification are listed in the REST api documentation: `/customerId`, `/description`, `/enabled`, `/labels`, `/name`, `/stages`. [1]
- The AWS Management Console does not support modification of the apikey value either. There is only the option to 'show' the apikey's value.

So if you want to change the value, you have to delete the existing apikey and create a new one. This includes recreating all the usageplankey resources which associate apikey resources with usageplan resources.

#### References

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/link-relation/apikey-update/#remarks

Comment: So I might be using the wrong resource, thank you for the explanation. Do you know if there is a right way to protect my api using mutable keys?

Comment: How often do you need to rotate apikeys? What is your usecase for apikeys? Do you give them to 3rd party vendors or customers? Do you use apikeys in conjunction with usageplans?

Comment: I wish to rotate at least one time per day. The keys are only for internal development, there are no 3rd party involve, but rotate the keys is a request from my boss, to keep it safe.
So, basically, we have some systems and some apps that are going to request the key and then, with the key, request the function it wants to access.
I think that at least the key to request other keys is going to be the same everytime, but if I could rotate it too would be great

Comment: I think apikeys are not designed by AWS to work that way. Let me elaborate why: From what I understand, you try to use apikeys to provide authentication to your lambda functions and thus have to rotate them to ensure they are "short-lived". However, apikeys are long-lived by design because they are used to provide "metering" only. An AWS employee states this in the support forum: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=193012

Comment: I got it, so I'm going to try develop one of the solutions pass by the AWS employee in the post. Thank you for helping me

Comment: "After you create an API key value, it cannot be changed.": https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-setup-api-key-with-console.html